# Seeing which page you are on (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a frontend mentor challenge that lists what page you are on next to the navbar.

[image: navbar example]

The horizontal home div is what I am having trouble with. If you are on the portfolio page, about page, it should say portfolio and about, etc.

It tried to use a prop and the onClick attribute to tell which page it was on, but it only showed up briefly while the button was currently being clicked. Does anyone else have another solution where the div will stay the same while I am on that page?

Here is my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pidgebean/arch-studio-react) if needed.

```
import React from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import logo from '../../assets/logo.svg'

export default function Navbar({page, setPage}) {
  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
      <div className='current-page'>{page}</div>
      <a href="/" className='home-btn' onClick={() => setPage('home')}>
        {/* <button>Home</button> */}
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
      </a>
      <a href="/portfolio" className='port-btn' onClick={() => setPage('Portfolio')}>
        <button className='btn-port'>Portfolio</button>
      </a>
      <a href="/about" className='about-btn' onClick={() => setPage('About Us')}>
        <button className='btn-about'>About Us</button>
      </a>
      <a href="/contact" className='contact-btn' onClick={() => setPage('Contact')}>
        <button className='btn-contact'>Contact</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but note that it is invalid HTML to put a `<button>` inside an `<a>`. Instead just use the `<a>` and use CSS to make it look like a button.

Comment: Frontend mentor tip: Don't ever dump a URL into a page. It's lazy and ugly. Create a proper, accessible link.

Comment: I suggest a glance at these [related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=conditionally+show+text+based+on+react+route+site:stackoverflow.com). What you want is conditional rendering based on route. No need to manually update the value. I might put the container element in the page and use a function to get the text based on route.

Comment: Firstly, though, you need to actually implement routing. React doesn't do well with conventional HTML links. You need to tell the app what's happening.